# Is it possible that I join a microscope and a telescope to view microscopic images of sand on the moon?

Tags: optics, astrophysics, astronomy, geometric-optics

A high power telescope can let me view images of the moon surface. The eyepiece of telescope can act like a virtual slide for the microscope and I view the sand grains' microscopic images. Is that possible?

Let's say I also point a laser light at that specific point to increase the light.

Answer (score 1):

> A high power telescope can let me view images of the moon surface. The eyepiece of telescope can act like a virtual slide for the microscope and I view the sand grains' microscopic images. Is that possible?

Someone has already mentioned the diffraction limit of the process, but there's also an issue with atmospheric blurring.  It's not a clean and empty vacuum between us and the moon, it's a dirty atmosphere with water vapor, ice crystals, cloud, dust and the whole thing is in constant motion from the small to the large scale.  Seeing grains of sand is not, therefore, possible  Try resolving small details on a distant ground target - you soon hit atmospheric haze and so on.

> Let's say I also point a laser light at that specific point to increase the light.

As some has mentioned the size of the resulting "spot" on the moon, I'll just mention [that purpose built mirrors were left on the moon by the Apollo astronauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment) are still used by firing a laser at the things and measuring the signal back, but that signal is very, very weak when it reaches us, and it's the return signal you'd be interested in.  A good return signal is just one or two photons per second.  Forming an image from that kind of power would be impractical and in fact the Moon already returns way more light just from the Sun (it's a very bright object).  The laser is simply used because it's easy to detect it and it has precise and repeatable properties as a signal that allow relatively simple and very precise measurements - something the continuous broad spectrum sunlight can't be used for.

As measured distance accuracy even with the very well calibrated telescope is nowhere near enough to resolve a grain of sand, so you'd not get much joy from using a laser to resolve surface detail at the level you describe.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, there are solutions to optically relay a microscope image to multiple observers. See for example this [multidiscussion solution](https://applications.zeiss.com/C125792900358A3F/0/855AA08701C3A253C12579E500429E7B/$FILE/60-2-0048_e_Multidiscussion.pdf). These solutions are used, if same color perception is important.

Would they work over the earth-moon distance? No, due to losses and imperfections.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible unless you have a perfect telescope and you compensated for the various movements of the Earth and Moon. Telescopes don't have perfect lenses, and therefore light isn't bent perfectly to form a perfect image. Also, the Earth and Moon move *very* quickly, so trying to move in such a way where you can focus on a grain of sand sounds pretty impossible.

Comment: but you can put some microscope like optics in front of a telescope and achieve a sensible effect?

Comment: It'd just be like using a different eyepiece, so I don't see why not. Perhaps you would have to shuffle the things together so they could focus reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that the limitation of telescope definition is not its magnification ratio (i.e. details too small to be seen), but diffraction (i.e. details blurred due to limitations imposed by Maxwell equations).

In other words, you need a fairly large viewing angle (tens of degrees) to get a decent resolution from a microscope objective. You would need the same viewing angle to see such details on the Moon - which means such a "micro-tele-scope" would have *several tens of thousands kilometres* in diameter. (See also https://xkcd.com/1294/)

Sure, it would also have to compensate for the motion of celestial bodies. Then yes, you could see microscopic details on the Moon surface.

Comment: Also pointing a laser at Moon does not produce a "spot" on its surface, but rather a smooth faintly illuminated area few kilometres across due to diffraction. See e.g. http://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/missions/apollo/apollo_11/experiments/lrr/